# Mongoose Connection outside NestJS for Lambda

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, lambda, nestjs

We are running nest.js on AWS Lambda similar to this: https://keyholesoftware.com/2019/05/13/aws-lambda-with-nestjs/

Unfortunately, the Mongoose part of nest.js does not close the database connections, so my MongoDB cluster is reaching a connection limit even if no one is working on it.

The best practices on Mongoose docs says this (defining it outside the context): https://mongoosejs.com/docs/lambda.html

Does anybody know how to achieve this in combination with the nest.js framework?

Comment: Please share some code so we can properly help :)

Comment: were you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

My first impression is to explicitly close connections, or set a timeout. However, I cannot seem to find anything approaching official documentation for nest.js for either of these options.

So: You have a database that doesn't automatically close idle connections, and a middleware that never closes connections, so your system is getting plugged. You could try putting something between them, to wait for idle and break the connection (even some firewalls may be talked into doing that). However, considering how impossible and/or undocumented proper connection handling is with these products, I suggest you rethink your choice of technologies.

Answer (score 0):

You must call **app.close()** after your function is executed to close mongoose connection.

example for AWS Cognito Lambda trigger:

```
    import { INestApplicationContext } from '@nestjs/common';

    let cachedApp: INestApplicationContext;
    async function bootstrap() {
      if (!cachedApp) {
        cachedApp = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(
          PreTokenGenerationModule
        );
      }
      return cachedApp;
    }

    export async function handler(
       event: CognitoUserPoolTriggerEvent,
       context: Context,
       callback: Callback
    ) {
       const app = await bootstrap();
       const preTokenGenerationService = app.get(PreTokenGenerationService);
       await preTokenGenerationService.execute(event, context, callback);
       app.close();
    }
```